# How many repetitions to establish difference

Tags: normal-distribution, confidence-interval, sampling, statistical-power

*(Real-world Context:
I often make changes to code, which I suspect will have small impacts on the performance. i.e. improvements that lie within the natural variation of the code's runtime.*

***How many reps of my perf test code do I need to run of the before/after code, in order to establish whether I have increased (or worse decreased!) the performance of my code?***

I think that the following precise mathematical question, is a reasonable proxy for that question, but I have no idea how to calculate the answer.

Suppose I have 2 random variables, $X \sim N(0,\sigma)$ and  $Y \sim N(\delta,\sigma)$

Suppose that I am going to take $N$ samples of $X$ and $Y$.

How many samples ($N$) must I take, in order to be able to assert, with $p = 0.95$ confidence, whether $\delta > 0$ or $\delta < 0$.

How many samples ($N$) must I take, in order to be able to assert, with $p = 0.95$ confidence, that $|\delta| < \epsilon$?.

---

Does it change things, if my variables are $X' \sim N(\mu,\sigma)$ and  $Y' \sim N(\mu \pm \delta,\sigma)$ ?

---

If it makes it easier to have the confidence threshold be arbitrary, feel free to leave it as $p$.

I'm assuming that once I've established the correct expression for $N_{enough}$, then my test will be:

- Take $N_{enough}$ samples of each.
- Average each sample set.
- Compare the averages.
- Report "yes" is the average satisfies the goal.

i.e. once I take "enough" samples the process is trivial, I just need to work out what is "enough".